# sparkling shadow sun glass shader

Tags: cycles-render-engine, rendering

thanks for support in advance.
while rendering in cycles the SHADOW of GLASS material is sparkling. Setting sun, but always the shadow looks like thousand stars. 
How do I create a black shadow and stop sparkling from GLASS material?

Comment: Can you show images that illustrate what you are getting, and a reference image what you are trying to achieve?

Answer (score 1):

Give this a try in the cycles node editor and see if it works for you.

This was taken from the following forum which should give you some assistance

[Blend Artist Glass](https://blenderartists.org/forum/showthread.php?344638-Glass-Shader-Problem&p=2696914&viewfull=1#post2696914)

[image: Cycles Glass]